# jquery find to get the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing `$(this).closest('.comment').find('form').toggle('slow');`  and the problem is each of the forms in the child is being toggled. I would like only the first form to be toggled. the html is something like the below and this is the a link

```
<div comment>
<a href>
<form>
</form>
    <a href>
    <div comment>
    <form>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You already got a good answer to this one, but next time please take the time to look at the documentation. JQuery is quite well documented, and you would have found the `:first` selector easily on your own had you only been looking for it... http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Comment: I did and couldnt find it. I am bad at jquery and this is my 2nd time using it. I just picked up the basics and already spend 1 hour on this and my prev question

Comment: Perhaps you didn't look in api.jquery.com but instead in the old documentation at docs.jquery.com, and I have to agree that due to the old documentation's structure it used to be very hard to find simple API functions like this one.

Answer (score 68):

You can use either

```
$(this).closest('.comment').find('form').eq(0).toggle('slow');
```

or

```
$(this).closest('.comment').find('form:first').toggle('slow');
```

Comment: second option worked for me, i had to select first div
jQuery(this).closest('.divmodule').find('div:first').attr('class'));

Comment: FYI, $('.foo:first') is quite a bit slower than $('.foo').first().  http://jsperf.com/jquery-first-vs-first-vs-eq-0-vs-0/2

Comment: If you really care about performance, native `getElementsByTagName` is way, way faster: http://jsperf.com/jquery-first-vs-first-vs-eq-0-vs-0/16

Comment: Does this first traverse the tree and then pick then first element?  Or does it somehow stop after finding the first element?  I ask because I'm dealing with a tree with hundreds of nested nodes but only want to select the first matching element.  I'm wondering if this method is grossly inefficient for this case.

Answer (score 14):

Use `:first` selector like below :

```
$(this).closest('.comment').find('form:first').toggle('slow');
```

Answer (score 8):

using jquery simply use:

```
    $( "form" ).first().toggle('slow');
```

Answer (score 5):

I use

```
$([selector]).slice(0, 1)
```

because it's the most explicit way to select a slice of a query and because it can be easily modified to match not the first element but the next, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get the first result of `find` is with good old `[index]` operator:

```
$('.comment').find('form')[0];
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
$(this).find('>.comment').find('>form').toggle('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since find get array of form elements the first one would be [0]. I would do this to make sure to get the first one.

```
$(this).closest('.comment').find('form')[0].toggle('slow');
```