# What is the equivalent for document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0] in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my selector in native JavaScript:

```
const textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
```

What is the equivalent in jQuery?

I have tried this with no luck:

```
const textarea = $("textarea")[0];
```

Here is another example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
  
    const textarea = $("p")[0];
    textarea.fadeOut();
    
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("p").fadeIn();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That **is** the equivalent. https://jsbin.com/puwozokaca/1/edit?js,console  We've no way of telling why you had no luck with it. You haven't provided a [mcve].

Comment: please look at the edit..

Comment: You're trying to call `fadeOut` on it. There's no fadeOut method on a DOM element. You'd get the same error if you tried `const textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];`

Comment: exactly... I want to select the first element by its tag using jQuery... that's what I asked...

Comment: @ Quentin BenM's answer is the solution...

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173971/jquery-find-to-get-the-first-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console tells you what the problem is:

> Uncaught TypeError: `textarea.fadeOut` is not a function

`fadeOut` and similar jQuery functions must be called on a jQuery object. When you access a jQuery object through array notation (i.e. `$('textarea')[0]`), you actually get a DOMElement.

If you want the first element of a specific type as a jQuery object, use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) or [`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/):

```js
$(".btn1").click(function() {
  const textarea = $("p").first();
  textarea.fadeOut();    
});

$(".btn2").click(function(){ $("p").fadeIn(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your working example. eq() let you specify the index of the element you are trying to get.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
  
    const textarea = $("p:eq(0)");
    textarea.fadeOut();
    
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("p").fadeIn();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in</button>

</body>
</html>
```