# jQuery alternative to selecting an element by chaining querySelector

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Given the following html:

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form" id="login">
        <h1 class="form__title">Login</h1>
        <div class="form__message form__message-error"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to reference the element of class "form__message" ? I know this is the only element of this class in this example, but potentially there could be more. So I was trying the following to remove the form__message-error CSS-properties:

```
 $("#login .form__message").classList.add("form__message--error");
```

This, however, does not find the correct element, whereas the following works:

```
document.querySelector("#login").querySelector(".form__message").classList.remove("form__message--error");
```

I am looking for a jQuery alternative to the last statement.

Comment: `$("#login .form__message").classList.add("form__message--error");` is not jQuery - you want  `$("#login .form__message").addClass("form__message--error");` and `$("#login .form__message").removeClass("form__message--error");` OR `$("#login .form__message").toggleClass("form__message--error");`

Comment: Hey, try something like this $(".form__message","#login").removeClass("form__message--error")

Comment: Why would `.classList.add()` *remove* a class?

Comment: `$('#login').find('.form__message').first().removeClass('form__message--error');` if you want the exact equivalent.

Comment: Either use the jQuery `addClass` method (`$("#login .form__message").addClass("form__message--error");` [or `.removeClass`]) or the DOM's `classList` (`document.querySelector("#login .form__message").classList.add("form__message--error").classList.add("form__message--error");` [or `.remove`]). Note that that latter (and yours in the question) assumes there's only one match for the selector. If there may be more than one, to get the equivalent effect to the jQuery code, you need `querySelectorAll` and a loop.

Comment: If you don't want to use jquery methods, you can always get the (first) DOM element using `[0]` : `$("#login .form__message")[0].classList...`

Comment: See also [jquery find to get the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2173971/215552)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing jQuery and DOM methods. The jQuery equivalent of `.classList.add()` is `.addClass()`.

```
$("#login .form__message").addClass("form__message--error");
```

You don't need `.find()` with `querySelector()`, you can use the same selector as with jQuery:

```
document.querySelector("#login .form__message").classList.add("form__message--error");
```

Comment: That is a typo-type question all day long. Already answered several times in the comments

Comment: There's no typos in the question - OP is looking for something they didn't know existed:  .addClass / .removeClass.

Comment: A duplicate in any case...

Comment: ^^ Look at all the point-rich people, arguing over why the question should be closed. - but yeah, this question is a duplicate at best.

Comment: @freedomn-m "typo-type"  for lack of a "you used the wrong or non-existing method as I will explain in my comment below your question so you can delete it"